# Unexpected index error while looping through workbooks in xlrd

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlrd, xlwt

I have a bunch of xlsx files, named from 1 to 169 like '1.xlsx', '2.xlsx' and so on... But while going through `for` loop, that read that files, the code does not see any rows in the 11th file (`nrows` in 11th file always is 0, while it is not if you open it manually) and gives me the IndexError (while these files are not empty).

I have no idea of what is going on with that code.

```
import os, xlwt, xlrd

file_dir = 'docs/'
files = os.listdir(file_dir)

#Open file and, read needed variables and write them
def r_file(path, file):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path+file)
    info_sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    data_sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(1)
    #cells with company info
    print info_sheet.nrows
    company_name = info_sheet.cell(3,3).value
    company_leg_adress = info_sheet.cell(4,3).value
    company_fact_adress = info_sheet.cell(5,3).value
    #cells with answers
    question_1 = data_sheet.cell(3,10).value
    question_1_1 = data_sheet.cell(8,2).value
    question_1_2 = data_sheet.cell(13,2).value
    question_2 = data_sheet.cell(18,10).value
    question_3 = data_sheet.cell(25,10).value
    question_3_additional = [data_sheet.cell(nrow,10).value for nrow in range(30,48)]
    question_4 = data_sheet.cell(51,2).value
    question_5 = data_sheet.cell(56,2).value
    
    #get full row in list
    row_as_list = [company_name,company_leg_adress,company_fact_adress, question_1, question_1_1, question_1_2, question_2, question_3, question_4]+question_3_additional
    return row_as_list

#write companies in file
def w_file(companies):
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    ws = wb.add_sheet('aggr', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    for company in companies:
        row_as_list = r_file(file_dir,str(company)+'.xlsx')
        for each_index in row_as_list:
            ws.write(company, row_as_list.index(each_index) , each_index)
    
    wb.save('aggregation.xls')
        
companies_amount = [x for x in range(1,170)]

w_file(companies_amount)
```

after running it, it returns:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/ex50/bin/writing.py", line 44, in <module>
    w_file(companies_amount)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/ex50/bin/writing.py", line 36, in w_file
    row_as_list = r_file(file_dir,str(company)+'.xlsx')
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/ex50/bin/writing.py", line 13, in r_file
    company_name = info_sheet.cell(3,3).value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/xlrd/sheet.py", line 401, in cell
    self._cell_types[rowx][colx],
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and it makes it only on the 11th file (no matter which file will be the 11th).

Can you tell me what is going on with that thing?

Comment: what about the number or columns? change the print into `print 'shape of %s is (%i, %i)' % (file, info_sheet.ncols, info_sheet.nrows)`

Comment: PS. use `enumerate` instead of the `row_as_list.index(each_index)`